# Почему игнорируется кодом 1-я часть

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
import time
a=input()# 1-я день 2-я ночь
c=input()
pyautogui.moveTo(115,221,duration=1)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.moveTo(1173,130,duration=1)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.moveTo(724,108,duration=1)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.moveTo(1115,206,duration=1)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.moveTo(328,603,duration=1)
pyautogui.click()
if c==1:
    if a==1:#1-я стадия день
        while a==1:
            for i in range (5):
                pyautogui.typewrite("text")
                pyautogui.moveTo(1144, 586,duration=1)
                pyautogui.click()
                pyautogui.click()
                pyautogui.click()
                pyautogui.moveTo(984, 593, duration=1)
                pyautogui.click()
                pyautogui.click()
                pyautogui.click()
                pyautogui.moveTo(328, 603, duration=1)
                pyautogui.click()
                time.sleep(60)
            time.sleep(120)
            c-=1
else:
    pyautogui.moveTo(1138,303,duration=1)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(328, 603, duration=1)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.typewrite(
            "break")
    pyautogui.moveTo(1144, 586, duration=1)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(984, 593, duration=1)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(3600)
    c+=1
```

Comment: я про конструкцию if else выполняется сразу else

Comment: print(type(c)) `<class 'str'>`

Comment: зачем не писать c?

Comment: просто напиши как сделать так чтобы выполнялось сначала if а потом уже else

Comment: c = int(input())

Answer (score 1):

```
c = int(input())
```

– S. Nick (спасибо)

Comment: У вас и `a` тоже будет строкой, а вы его проверяете с числом. Так что и `a = int(input())` тоже надо сделать.